# How to build my Qt/MSbuild project in Github actions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, msbuild, github-actions

My project is developed in Qt C++ in Windows environment.
I want to build on Github actions by using msbuild and windeployqt.

This is my example yml script

```
name: MSBuild

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

env:
  # Path to the solution file relative to the root of the project.
  SOLUTION_FILE_PATH: ..
  QT_VERSION:   6.4.3

  # Configuration type to build.
  # You can convert this to a build matrix if you need coverage of multiple configuration types.
  # https://docs.github.com/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#using-a-build-matrix
  BUILD_CONFIGURATION: Release

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
   runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
- name: (1) Checkout repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v3

- name: (2) Install Qt
  uses: jurplel/install-qt-action@v3
  with:
    version:      ${{ env.QT_VERSION }}
    host:         windows
    target:       desktop
    arch:         win64_msvc2019_64
    dir:          ${{ runner.temp }}
    setup-python: false 
    
- name: (4) Add MSBuild to PATH
  uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

- name: Create build folder
  run: mkdir -p ${{ runner.temp }}\build

- name: (5) Build with msbuild
  working-directory: ${{ runner.temp }}\build
  run: echo "Start building in ${{ runner.temp }}\build"
       cd ${{ runner.temp }}\build
       msbuild /m /p:Configuration=${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} ${{ github.workspace }}\xxx.sln

- name: (6) List contents of the build directory
  run: |
    ls -R ${{ runner.temp }}\build
    
#- name: (6) Deploy with windeployqt
#  working-directory: ${{ runner.temp }}
#  run: |
#    mkdir ${{ env.DEPLOY_DIR }}
#    windeployqt --dir ${{ env.DEPLOY_DIR }} ${{ env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH }}/path/to/my/exe
```

But after step 5 and 6, nothing happened.
There's even no any error message that I can check if the source code is built correctly.

Can someone teach me how to build it with MSbuild and windeployqt?

Thanks!

**Update:** after syntax errors fixed:

```
- name: (2) Install Qt
  uses: jurplel/install-qt-action@v3
  with:
    version:      ${{ env.QT_VERSION }}
    host:         windows
    target:       desktop
    arch:         win64_msvc2019_64
    dir:          ${{ runner.temp }}
    setup-python: false 
    
- name: Print Qt version information
  run: |
    qmake -v
    
- name: (3) Add MSBuild to PATH
  uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

- name: (4) Create build folder
  run: |
       mkdir -p ${{ runner.temp }}\build

- name: (5) Set Qt Environment Variables
  run: |
    echo "Setting Qt Environment Variables"
       echo "QTDIR=${{ runner.temp }}/Qt/${{ env.QT_VERSION }}/msvc2019_64" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       echo "QtToolsPath=${{ runner.temp }}/Qt/${{ env.QT_VERSION }}/msvc2019_64/bin" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: bash

- name: (6) Build with msbuild
  working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}
  run: |
       echo "Current directory: $($PWD.Path)"
       msbuild /p:Configuration=${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} /p:OutDir=${{ runner.temp }}\build\ "${{ env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH }}\QtStockV3.sln"
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
Q: How to include path in github action?

In the section below "Set Qt Environment Variables and path", I set several include path which contain my header files.

But according to the error msg, it didn't find the header files there?

I'll provide a complete example here, after I resolve all of this.
And thanks for your help!

[image]

```
- name: (5) Install Vcpkg and cURL 
  working-directory: ${{ runner.temp }}
  run: |
    git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
    cd vcpkg
    .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
    .\vcpkg install curl
    curl --version

- name: Set Qt Environment Variables and path
  run: |
       echo "QTDIR=${{ runner.temp }}/Qt/${{ env.QT_VERSION }}/msvc2019_64" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       echo "QtToolsPath=${{ runner.temp }}/Qt/${{ env.QT_VERSION }}/msvc2019_64/bin" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       echo "INCLUDE_PATH_1=${{ github.workspace }}/${{ env.PROJ_NAME }}/src/header" >> $GITHUB_PATH
       echo "INCLUDE_PATH_2=${{ github.workspace }}/${{ env.PROJ_NAME }}/src/parser" >> $GITHUB_PATH
       echo "INCLUDE_PATH_3=${{ github.workspace }}/${{ env.PROJ_NAME }}/src/cc" >> $GITHUB_PATH
       echo "INCLUDE_PATH_VCPKG=${{ runner.temp }}/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include" >> $GITHUB_PATH
       ls ${INCLUDE_PATH_1}
       ls ${INCLUDE_PATH_2}
       ls ${INCLUDE_PATH_3}
  shell: bash

    
- name: (7) Build with msbuild
  working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}
  run: |
       echo "Current directory: $($PWD.Path)"
       msbuild /p:Configuration=${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} /p:OutDir=${{ runner.temp }}\build\ "${{ env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH }}\QtStockV3.sln"
```

[image]

**Update 3**
The way I use $GITHUB_PATH and $GITHUB_ENV seems not work.
I installed json in the same way I installed in local.

The pkg was installed properly but still see the error msg in log.

```
- name: Install nlohmann JSON
  working-directory: ${{ runner.temp }}
  run: |
        git clone https://github.com//json.git
        cd json
        echo "${{ runner.temp }}\json\include" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        ls "${{ runner.temp }}\json\include"
```

[image]

[image]

**Update 4:**
I installed json with vcpkg, then the errors left are related to header files path.

To simplified the including path, I move all of my headers to the same folder with .cc

update: I noticed that the path to my header file was not included in the list. But how to do this? To modify the vcxproj file locally?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Make your step 5 multiline as you're doing in step 6 using `|`. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun for example from docs.

Comment: Also, the indentation in your workflow is off i.e. `steps`. You need to fix that.

Comment: You may use lint your workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to fix the typos.

Comment: @Azeem oh oh, nice tool, thanks! But actually what i want to know is the flow.

Comment: Please add your updated workflow in your question under an UPDATE section.

Comment: IIRC, you need to set `QTDIR` and `QtToolsPath` env vars before your build step. You may use `QT_ROOT_DIR` to set these e.g. in a separate step with Bash you can do `echo "QTDIR=$QT_ROOT_DIR" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"` and `echo "QtToolsPath=$QT_ROOT_DIR/bin" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`. It was awhile ago when I had to figure this out by backtracking from `Qt.props` and other files in the `QtMsBuild` directory along with VS QtTool configurations.

Comment: `QT_ROOT_DIR` is already being set by `jurplel/install-qt-action`. You can use it instead of creating the path yourself. That's what I hinted at in my previous comment. While setting env vars, use `/` for path separator. Also, please don't replace your errors in the questions. Paste them as text under new UPDATE section(s) as your encounter those.

Comment: @Azeem Got it! Thanks a lot, the env variable settings success. but there's another error...

Comment: You need to configure charts with [`modules`](https://github.com/jurplel/install-qt-action?tab=readme-ov-file#modules) i.e. `modules: qcharts`.  Also, configure [`cache`](https://github.com/jurplel/install-qt-action?tab=readme-ov-file#cache) i.e. `cache: true`.

Comment: Typo in my above comment: `qcharts` => `qtcharts`

Comment: @Azeem, Hi I've updated to question, do you have any idea? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apparently, missing `vcpkg integrate install`. See https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html.

Comment: I add this cmd "vcpkg integrate install" then curl lib is installed completely. But still can not find the header files I included in .cc files. Did I include the GITHUB_PATH in a wrong way?

Comment: It looks related to your include header paths in your build configuration. You need to verify those.

Comment: I uploaded a snapshot from log. In row 8, I listed all files below header folder which shows in row 19~23.

Comment: Right. The files exist. Have you checked the project file for the include directories' paths?  Have you built it locally?

Comment: yep, I used to build locally with visual studio, and there's no error.

Comment: If i want to move my project from local to github action, do i need to modified include path in vcxproj to relative path?

Comment: You need to build it successfully on your local setup from the command line. If it works there with relative paths i.e. moving it to any other path doesn't break the build, then it should build on your GHA workflow too using the identical configuration.

Comment: Sure, I worked with two different laptops. I built successful on both of them. Actually, I noticed that the way I used to include path in script seems not works correctly. Please see the section I updated, thanks!

Comment: Why are you not installing nlohmann::json with `vcpkg`? Isn't your compiler configuration pointing to vcpkg's installed directory for all the libs? Also, the env var name is missing in your last workflow.

Comment: The path in your `cl.exe` command for JSON lib is `C:\Installation\json\include` which is not what `nlohmann::json` path you're using with `#include` directive. You need to fix these inclusions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is the first time I thought of installing nlohmann::json this way. hahaha.

Comment: The remaining error messages so far are all related to the header files. Does that mean I have to modify the vxcproj file?

Comment: I answer my question, seems like I have to modify vcxproj file locally. I add the path e.g D:\a\<project_name>\ which is an absolute path in GHA env in visual studio and build successful finally. Thank you @Azeem.

Comment: Yes, these paths need to be updated. Sure, you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you need to set `QTDIR` and `QtToolsPath` env vars before your build step. You may use `QT_ROOT_DIR` to set these in a separate step (see example below with Bash):

```yaml
- name: Set QTDIR and QtToolsPath
  shell: bash
  run: |
    echo "QTDIR=$QT_ROOT_DIR" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
    echo "QtToolsPath=$QT_ROOT_DIR/bin" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

- name: Build
  run: ...
```

where, `QT_ROOT_DIR` represents the Qt installation directory.

See `jurplel/install-qt-action`'s [`dir`](https://github.com/jurplel/install-qt-action) input parameter for more details on `QT_ROOT_DIR`.

---

Depending on your application, you may need to configure [`modules`](https://github.com/jurplel/install-qt-action?tab=readme-ov-file#modules) input parameter to install Qt modules which are not installed by default.

Apart from that, you might want to enable caching to speed up your workflow runs i.e. `cache: true`. See [`cache`](https://github.com/jurplel/install-qt-action?tab=readme-ov-file#cache) input parameter for more details.