# Compiling a Qt4 project with GitHub Actions on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, github-actions, qt4

I have an old Qt4 project that I’ve been able to compile on Ubuntu, but I’m struggling to do the same on Windows using GitHub Actions. I’ve searched extensively online but haven’t found any resources that address this specific issue.

Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide or point me to a resource that explains how to set up a GitHub Actions workflow for compiling a Qt4 project on a Windows runner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

my ubuntu yaml script:

```
name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        project:
          [
            { folder: "breft_editor", target: "breft" },
            { folder: "neko", target: "nekofile" },
            { folder: "mipatch", target: "Mipatcher" },
            { folder: "plisteditors", target: "plist" },
            { folder: "ohneschwanzenegger", target: "refleurii" },
            { folder: "tpune", target: "punetween" },
            { folder: "symbolizer", target: "symbolizer" },
          ]
      fail-fast: false

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup dependencies
        run: |
          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/ppa -y
          sudo apt install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtgui4 g++ -y

      - name: Compile
        run: |
          cd ${{ matrix.project.folder }}
          qmake -qt=qt4 ${{ matrix.project.target }}.pro
          make -f Makefile
     
      - name: Upload Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.3.0
        with:
          name: build-artifacts-${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }}-${{ matrix.project.target }}
          path: |
            ${{ matrix.project.folder }}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77506462/7670262.

Comment: the jurplel/install-qt-action@v3 script doesn't support qt4, so that answer is pretty much useless to my needs.